# SQL Query result return set for same id with differing value

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I need to run a compare and return differences. I am finding it tough to express the SQL query in a syntax that works. The logic is there and I can explain but the syntax alludes me, can you help?

I have 1 table (locations) in a schema that hosts 2 primary keys 'locationID' and 'materialID'. Now i hold 3 locations in my table - PlayM PlayB and Ing. It is often the case that I have a materialID available on each location.

What I require to check is the integer value duration for each materialID on each locationID. If one the durations is not matching its peers for a result to return with all materialID on each location with the discrepancy under duration.

Example;

```
+------------+------------+----------+
| LOCATIONID | MATERIALID | DURATION |
+------------+------------+----------+
| PlayM      | Clip1      |      626 |
| PlayB      | Clip1      |      626 |
| Ing        | Clip1      |      626 |
| PlayM      | Clip2      |      600 |
| PlayB      | Clip2      |      590 |
| Ing        | Clip2      |      600 |
+------------+------------+----------+
```

Clip1 would not return a result as all location have the same duration. However clip 2 should report all 3 as one of the durations differ.

My example query would be as follows... note I am lost when referring to not equal :(

```
SELECT * FROM locations
WHERE materialID IN (SELECT materialID WHERE duration <>
```

Can you help?

Thanks....

SQL Learn

Comment: What database are you using?  Tag the question appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

If it's `SQL SERVER` you're using:

```
;with cte as(
    select
        *,
        cc = count(*) over(partition by MaterialId),
        ccc = count(*) over(partition by MaterialId, Duration)
    from Locations
)
select 
    LocationId,
    MaterialId,
    Duration
from cte
where cc <> ccc
```